# Autowire singleton bean inside a prototype bean with proxy TARGET_CLASS

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have three classes as below.

```
@Service(value="singleOuter")
public class SingletonBeanOuter {
    @Autowired
    public SingletonBeanInner sbi;
    @Autowired
    public PrototypeBean pb;
    public SingletonBeanOuter()
    {
    System.out.println("Singleton OUTER Bean instance creation");
    }
}

@Service(value="prot")
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
public class PrototypeBean{
    public PrototypeBean()
    {
        System.out.println("Prototype Bean instance creation");
    }
    @Autowired
    public SingletonBeanInner sbi;
}

@Service(value="singleInner")
public class SingletonBeanInner {
    public SingletonBeanInner()
    {
        System.out.println("Singleton Bean INNER instance creation");
    }
}
```

HERE: When i try to access instance of `SingletonBeanInner` through `SingletonBeanOuter`->prototype it returns null.

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
         SingletonBeanOuter a = context.getBean("singleOuter", SingletonBeanOuter.class);
                System.out.println("=================================================================");
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(a.sbi);
    System.out.println(a.pb);
    System.out.println(a.pb.sbi); //Returns null
    System.out.println("=================================================================");
    SingletonBeanOuter b = context.getBean("singleOuter", SingletonBeanOuter.class);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(b.sbi);
    System.out.println(b.pb);
    System.out.println(b.pb.sbi); //Returns null
    }
}
```

My intention here is get the singleton instance of `SingletonBeanInner` when i access it from `PrototypeBean` with the TARGET_CLASS proxy setting.

Comment: Which is as expected. The `a.pb` and `b.pb` are proxies for an actual instance `pb`. You are getting the field of the proxy, instead of the actual instance. Basically what you do will not work with proxies. You have to make the fields private and provide getters, that way it will work.

Comment: It worked with private. Thanks.